# A function for every image to preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the [jsfile](https://jsfiddle.net/hrxnne9q/7/)

Here is my function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('.img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $(".input-upload").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
         console.log(this.id);
    });


});
```

My problem is the class i'm using..I need to create this function with parameters or something to work for every input and image ..now is working just for one an input but need to be dinamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `input` to target [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) `img` element in the `onload` handler of `FileReader`

```
$(input).siblings('img.img-upload').prop('src', e.target.result);
```

Here is simplified [**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/hrxnne9q/8/)

*or*

```
$(input).closest('.pic-box').find('img.img-upload').prop('src', e.target.result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Alter the `src` using the variable `input` to get the image relative to the selected input:

```
$(input).closest('.fileContainer').find('.img-upload').attr('src', e.target.result);
```

Comment: What does `this` refer in `onload` handler?

Comment: @Satpal ups my bad :(